# AO node not working

Tags: texturing, ambient-occlusion

I have to do some edge wear in the shader editor, but as soon as I use the *AO* node, the object goes to *Missing Texture*, I noticed that it only does this in SSRT Blender.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by SSRT Blender? Do you mean the SSRT shader which is no official part of Blender? I'm sorry, I guess you should ask the developer for this since on this site we are trying to solve problems with tools and addons shipped with Blender.

Comment: I guess these two are not compatible.

Comment: Could be wrong.. but since AO depends on probes shot in world space, naively, I wouldn't see a way SSRT can implement it. Is this is a limitation of a third-party add-on? ( I think it would probably be unfair to call it a bug).